# sql parse error: T_VARIABLE

Tags: php, sql

I am getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$sql' (T_VARIABLE) in the following sql statement. Can anyone help??

```
$sql = "SELECT items, price FROM shop_table WHERE shop = '$shop' AND stations = '$station'";
```

Comment: Error not from this line of code.. pls add more code. Line number will be showing with php error

Comment: the problem probably is that the line before your SQL query is missing semicolon (;). The error begins in $sql so it has to be something before.

Comment: my bad, missed the semicolon. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem probably is that the line before your SQL query is `missing semicolon (;)`. The error begins in $sql so it has to be something before.